# Spring Boot not fetching Keycloak Roles

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm trying to implement role based authentication in my Spring Boot app which uses Keycloak. I defined a realm role and I annotated my controller with a @RolesAllowed, it didn't use the roles defined in Keycloak. Attached is SecurityConfiguration to show how I attempted to define authorization and authentication and a snippet from the WorkQueue controller class.

SecurityConfiguration.java:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.configurations;

import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakConfiguration;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;



// configure in extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
@KeycloakConfiguration
@Import(KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = new KeycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers(
                // Client-side JS
                // TODO
                // "/**",

                // the standard favicon URI
                "/favicon.ico",

                // the robots exclusion standard
                "/robots.txt",

                // web application manifest
                "/manifest.webmanifest", "/sw.js", "/offline.html",
                
                // icons and images
                "/icons/**", "/images/**", "/styles/**", "/css/**", "/js/**",
                "/sw-runtime-resources-precache.js");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/work_queue/**").permitAll()//hasRole("myapp")
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
                
//              .permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2Login();
//              .formLogin()
//              .loginPage("/login")
//              .permitAll();

    }

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(buildSessionRegistry());
    }

    @Bean
    protected SessionRegistry buildSessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }
}
```

Snippet from WorkQueueController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/work_queue")
public class WorkQueueController
    @GetMapping
    @RolesAllowed("my-role")  // Line A
    public String work_queue(Principal principal, Model model) {
        log.debug("Principal is a "+principal.getClass().getName());
        OAuth2AuthenticationToken token = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) principal; 
        Object principal2 = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
        for(GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
            log.debug("Authority: "+authority.getAuthority());
        }
        
        log.debug("Principal2 is a "+principal2.getClass().getName());      
        DefaultOidcUser user = null;
        if(user!=null && user instanceof DefaultOidcUser) {
            user = (DefaultOidcUser) principal2;
        }

//      log.debug("Roles "+simpleKeycloakAccount.getRoles());
        Object principal3 = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if(principal3 != null && principal3 instanceof DefaultOidcUser) {
            DefaultOidcUser user3 = (DefaultOidcUser)principal3;
//          user = (DefaultOidcUser) principal;
            for(String key : user3.getAttributes().keySet()) {
                Object value = user3.getAttributes().get(key);
                log.debug("user3 key={} value={}",key,value);
            }
    
        }

    }
```

When Line A is present, I get a 403 (forbidden). When I comment line A, the method executes, and I'm able to see values I defined in Keycloak:

```
Principal is a org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken
Authority: ROLE_USER
Authority: SCOPE_email
Authority: SCOPE_openid
Authority: SCOPE_profile
Principal2 is a org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser
user3 key=at_hash value=<some-hash-value>
user3 key=sub value=<some-guid>
user3 key=email_verified value=true
user3 key=iss value=https://auth.mycompanytest.com/auth/realms/MyRealmk
user3 key=typ value=ID
user3 key=preferred_username value=ben.pracht@ruralsourcing.com
user3 key=given_name value=Woods
user3 key=nonce value=CZfW09_IKZbF5e0QhL-cDC4Uvk0QIJvmMqys0VmczlQ
user3 key=aud value=[myapp-app]
user3 key=acr value=0
user3 key=azp value=myapp-app
user3 key=auth_time value=2022-06-20T22:56:52Z
user3 key=name value=Woods Man
user3 key=exp value=2022-06-20T23:11:44Z
user3 key=session_state value=aa3e95e1-47e5-463b-a599-bf486a40fc00
user3 key=family_name value=Man
user3 key=iat value=2022-06-20T23:06:44Z
user3 key=email value=<my-email-address>
user3 key=jti value=d0f1b89f-ee20-424f-b12e-1ea869f5e712
```

So, I conclude that it reached Keycloak, but it decided to *not* use or fetch Keycloak roles. Why?

Bonus points for telling me if how a role defined in a client works differently than a role defined in a realm.

<note: for privacy reasons, various things above hidden to protect the innocent>

Comment: *Bonus points for telling me if how a role defined in a client works differently than a role defined in a realm.*: The user get's the role defined in a client only assigned when the user authenticates for that specific client. Otherwise the JWT will only contain the user assigned roles.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWosch. I know I don't do JWT.  What more do I need to add to get that?

Comment: What do you mean with you don't do JWT? Based on the log output the keys match the claims of a JWT. Further - afair `@RolesAllowed()` checks of the provided role name **plus** `ROLE_` as prefix. Based on your example - have you tried to use `@RolesAllowed("ROLE_USER")` for testing purpose? As this role seems to be set in your authentication.

Comment: Further question: How does the authentication exactly look like? Meaning: What do you do / send when you are running into this issue

Comment: I meant I didn't code anything explicitly for JWT. I don't know what extra steps and flows it takes to get a JWT. I tested  ROLE_myrole, ROLE_MYROLE and myrole. @RoleAllowed("user") works though.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what flow Spring Boot goes through to get this. I know I'd start with an authorization request, then a call to get access token. I think somewhere I'd request oidc, but not sure when to get jwt. Thats for manual calls. Spring Boot could be doing something different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245779/discussion-between-woodsman-and-daniel-wosch).