# Keycloak refuses to return roles on request

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

My Keycloak is returning an OAuth2AuthenticationToken, but refuses to add the roles the user has. Instead, it's returning the somewhat generic:

```
Authority: ROLE_USER
Authority: SCOPE_email
Authority: SCOPE_openid
Authority: SCOPE_profile
```

The Java method is

```
    @GetMapping
    public String work_queue(Principal principal, Model model) {
       ...
       //Principal comes in as org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken

      // 
        Object principal2 = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

     // principal2 is org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser

    }
```

In Postman, I was able to convince Keycloak to return a JWT token using the Get Token functionality. Inside the JWT, after decompiling, I saw all the roles I wanted it to see. Yet somehow, the Spring Boot configuration decided to shorten this down to something much smaller.

What would someone need to know to guess a good solution?

Please see [Spring Boot not fetching Keycloak Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72693889/spring-boot-not-fetching-keycloak-roles)

Comment: I don't see any refuse. Keycloak returns only what is configured.

Comment: At which point do you get the authorities you listed above? `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` Should return an instance of the `Authentication` interface containing the authorities: `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities();`

Comment: @DanielWosch Thanks for your reply. Please see the related question which shows configuration and the api endpoint.

Comment: To Jan Garaj: I updated with a related question. The roles are defined in KC. What does it take to get them visible to the @Roles annotations?

Comment: You need an overidden `JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter` `@Bean`, but you can do simpler / better / faster with my answer below

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a `@Bean` implementing `Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>>` to override Spring's `JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter` (it is this bean mapping scopes to authorities).

But, you could use a lib I worte for spring-boot OpenID resource-servers auto-configuration (works with any OIDC authorization-server, Keycloak included) which might save you a lot of configuration and provide you with a more OpenID oriented `Authentication` than `JwtAuthenticationToken`: [`OAuthentication<OpenidClaimSet>`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-addons-oauth2/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/OAuthentication.java), which exposes [`OpenidClaimSet`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-addons-oauth2/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/OpenidClaimSet.java) as principal.

It's available from maven-central and source is there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons.

This very [simple tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_oauthentication) should be enough (you can refer to [this other one](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_specialized_oauthentication) for more advanced use-cases):

- spring-boot app with those dependencies:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-webmvc-addons</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-test-webmvc-addons</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

- that java config

```java
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public static class WebSecurityConfig {
}
```

- those properties

```
# shoud be set to where your authorization-server is
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.token-issuers[0].location=https://localhost:9443/auth/realms/master

# shoud be configured with a list of private-claims this authorization-server puts user roles into
# below is default Keycloak conf for a `spring-addons` client with client roles mapper enabled
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.token-issuers[0].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,resource_access.spring-addons.roles

# advanced CORS configuration can be made per API route
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/greet/**
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].allowed-origins=https://localhost,https://localhost:8100,https://localhost:4200

# use IDE auto-completion or see SpringAddonsSecurityProperties javadoc for complete configuration properties list to change defaults:
# - anonymous enabled
# - empty list of permitAll() routes
# - CSRF disabled
# - stateless session management
# - case and prefix for mapped authorities
# - 401 (unauthorized) instead of 302 (redirect to login)
# - CORS allowed methods, headers, etc. for each path
```

Yes, with 2 dependencies, 1 configuration line and 4 properties, we just configured an OpenID resource-server with CORS and authorities mapping from random private claims (plus a few other things useful to resource servers). Could it be simpler?

As an extra bonus, it comes with annotations to configure your unit-tests security context (this is from the third dependency):

```java
@WebMvcTest(GreetingController.class)
@AutoConfigureSecurityAddons
@Import(WebSecurityConfig.class)
class GreetingControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @OpenId(authorities = { "NICE_GUY", "AUTHOR" }, claims = @OpenIdClaims(preferredUsername = "Tonton Pirate"))
    void whenGrantedWithNiceGuyThenCanGreet() throws Exception {
        mockMvc
                .perform(get("/greet").secure(true))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string("Hi Tonton Pirate! You are granted with: [NICE_GUY, AUTHOR]."));
    }

    @Test
    @OpenId(authorities = { "AUTHOR" }, claims = @OpenIdClaims(preferredUsername = "Tonton Pirate"))
    void whenNotGrantedWithNiceGuyThenForbidden() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/greet").secure(true)).andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }

}
```

P.S.
Please give a star to https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons if you find it useful.